# Show errors for current target only in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updated to Xcode 14.1 and noticed that when I build my app (which has 4 targets) and if there are some errors, it shows the same error for all the targets and not for just the target that I'm working on like the following so that makes the error count goes to `noOfTargets*noOfActualCodebaseError`, in my case (for 1 error) go 4 rather than 1 like the following:

[image]

(Also, the issues count in the images are wayyyyyy off)

Is there a way to just get the error for the target that I am working on or that I have selected?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the same problem except I have 27 targets!  Thx

Comment: @nurider No. I didn't so far. It's kind of frustrating that there is no solution to this